# ExportFactory Mef 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mef

I understand that in MEF 2 preview 2 the ExportFactory has now been moved to the desktop. Does this mean that you can now use it in MVC?

If so does anyone know of an example as I would like to dynamically create parts in a Lazy way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can, as long as you're using our codeplex drop (assembly name ends with .Codeplex).

ExportFactory and Lazy have different purposes. You can have a lazy import:

```
[Import]
public Lazy<MyDependency> Dep { get; set; }
```

This would allow you to instantiate MyDependency when needed, using Dep.Value, but only once. 
ExportFactory allows you to create as many instances as you want, as needed.